# Separate URL for front side and administrator using Angular IO

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I want to make separate URL for front side and administrator in one app using Angular IO.

For Example:

```
Front URL: http://localhost:4200/

Administrator URL: http://localhost:4200/admin
```

Please suggest me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

Assuming you have separate components for front as well as Admin URL.

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [

      { path: '', component: DefaultComponent },

      { path: 'admin',component: AdminComponent }

    ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes
    )

  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

With above,

For Front URL: `http://localhost:4200/`, DefaultComponent  will be called

Administrator URL: `http://localhost:4200/admin`, AdminComponent will be called

**Important !** Dont forget to mention component selector `<my-app></my-app>` in .html file

Comment: is it any different from the answer by @Markus?

Comment: Nope. Coz this is the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your response but which structure should i follow for this?
Ex: for front side: app/app.module.ts, app/app.component.ts, app/app.component.html

For Admin: app/admin/app.module.ts, app/admin/app.component.ts, app/admin/app.component.html

Comment: front side: app/app/modeule.ts, app/app.component.ts, app/app.component.html . for admin: app/admin/admin.component.ts, app/admin/admin.component.html. app.module.ts you can keep common, and add above code in app.module.ts which will be accessible to both component. you va eto import both components in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Import the RouterModule in your app.module.ts like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    loadChildren: './front/front.module#FrontModule'
  },
  { 
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    ...
  ],
  providers: [ ... ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And inside of your admin- and front-modules, you also have to import the RouterModule like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AdminComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ...
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

And add the `router-outlet` to your app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but which structure should i follow for this?

Comment: What do you mean with structure?

Comment: Ex: for front side: app/app.module.ts, app/app.component.ts, app/app.component.html For Admin: app/admin/adminapp.module.ts, app/admin/app.component.ts, app/admin/app.component.html

Comment: Aaah, I see. You don't need separate modules for admin and front, unless you want lazy loading. Just generate the component with "ng g component admin" and "ng g component front".

Comment: I have created many modules for admin and now working for front modules. So I want to separate module. 

Ex: For front: 
app/registration
app/login
app/products

For Admin:
app/admin/login
app/admin/products

Can we do like this?

Comment: Yes. Check my update. This lazy loads your modules :-)

Comment: Thanks @Markus Kollers. Let me try this one.